# tun0 errors when running a vpn server?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, ufw

I'm running a simple vpn server with these softwares:

- OpenVPN
- Shadowsocks
- MTProto Proxy

My server config is:

- Ubuntu 18.04 x64
- 512Ram, 1vCPU
- UFW firewall
- Netdata monitoring
- Nginx

It's been only few days since I started running the server. Problem is Netdata keeps sending me these 3 type of errors every few hours.

- "server needs attention, ipv4.udperrors (udp), 1m ipv4 udp receive buffer errors = 12 errors"
- "server needs attention, net_drops.tun0 (tun0), outbound packets
  dropped = 34 packets"
- "server needs attention, net_packets.tun0 (tun0), outbound packets
  dropped ratio = 0.33%"

I thought it's not that of a big deal so I ignored them.

I'm not sure if this is a firewall issue, a system bottleneck, or one of the 3 mentioned vpn softwares are not performing well.

I looked into almost every log file in `/var/log` but I couldn't find any error or problem before server went unreachable. I'm not sure if the server froze, or crashed. cause there is no log after a certain point. not until we did force a reboot.

Comment: most rental vps are blocked for tap/tun Devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. It was openvpn related. I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and apparently openvpn had an issue doing TLS handshake with the client. And it kept logging these errors:

```
TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS handshake failed
```

The reason was the `reneg-sec` parameter which had the default values of 3600. Here is a quote from openvpn's official docs:

> –reneg-sec n
>
> Renegotiate data channel key after n seconds (default=3600).When using
>   dual-factor authentication, note that this default value may cause the
>   end user to be challenged to reauthorize once per hour.
>
> Also, keep in mind that this option can be used on both the client and
>   server, and whichever uses the lower value will be the one to trigger
>   the renegotiation. A common mistake is to set –reneg-sec to a higher
>   value on either the client or server, while the other side of the
>   connection is still using the default value of 3600 seconds, meaning
>   that the renegotiation will still occur once per 3600 seconds. The
>   solution is to increase –reneg-sec on both the client and server, or
>   set it to 0 on one side of the connection (to disable), and to your
>   chosen value on the other side.

This parameter makes sure the client has to renegotiate their key every hour.

So if you left the openvpn on (client side) for a long time, and if for whatever reason one of the handshakes fails It would cause an endless supply of failed negotiations. I guess that caused the dropped packets and stuff.

Not to mention the "tun0" interface was made by openvpn in the first place, which I didn't know.

**Anyway the solution** is to change the `reneg-sec` to either a higher value, or just set it to zero and disable it. I decided to just go with the disable option and put `reneg-sec 0` in `server.conf` and client `.opvn` profiles.

Also if you happen to use UFW, you have to edit `/etc/default/ufw` and change
`DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY`to accept.

If you still keep getting udp errors you probably also need to tweak your networking settings.